# Calculations related to $(\Delta w_j,\Delta w_k)=\iiint \Delta w_j \cdot \Delta w_k$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Define

$$(\Delta w_j, \ \Delta w_k)=\iiint  \Delta w_j \cdot \Delta w_k=(\Delta w_k, \ \Delta w_j)$$

Then

\begin{align}
\left( \sum c_k \Delta w_k, \ \sum c_j \Delta w_j \right) &= (c_1 \Delta w_1 + \dots + c_n \Delta w_n, \ c_1 \Delta w_1 + \dots + c_n \Delta w_n) \\\\ 
&= \iiint c_1^2 \Delta w_1 \cdot \Delta w_1 + \dots + c_n^2 \Delta w_n \cdot \Delta w_n + c_1 c_2 \Delta w_1 \cdot \Delta w_2 \\ 
& \ \ \ \ + c_2 c_1 \Delta w_2 \cdot \Delta w_1 + \dots d \mathbf{x} \\\\
&= \sum (\Delta w_j, \Delta w_j) c_j^2 + 2 \sum \sum_{j \neq k} (\Delta w_k, \ \Delta w_j) c_k c_j
\end{align}

**Question**

Why do the terms $c_1c_2 \Delta w_1 \cdot \Delta w_2 + c_2 c_1 \Delta w_2 \cdot \Delta w_1 + ...$ were added in the triple integral if it's supossed to be a dot product, i.e. $x\cdot y=x_1y_1+\dots+x_ny_n$?

Comment: It comes from the cross terms. Using the definition of an inner product might help $$\langle u + v, w \rangle = \langle u, w \rangle + \langle v, w \rangle$$

Comment: @Mattos That clarifies a little bit more. But the number $2$ I don't see where it comes from. I already saw were $\sum\sum_{j\neq k}$ comes from.

Comment: The $2$ comes from the fact that $$c_{1} c_{2} \Delta w_{1} \cdot \Delta w_{2} = c_{2} c_{1} \Delta w_{2} \cdot \Delta w_{1}$$ from your definition, and hence $$c_{1} c_{2} \Delta w_{1} \cdot \Delta w_{2} + c_{2} c_{1} \Delta w_{2} \cdot \Delta w_{1} = \color{red} 2 c_{1} c_{2} \Delta w_{1} \cdot \Delta w_{2} $$

Comment: @Mattos ok, thank you.